# find out who watched my telegram Avatar

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Recently, There are new robots that claim to be able to tell who has seen your profile photo but most of them are fake.

I want to know is it actually possible to write that bot? Directly by using bot api or indirectly like creating a channel for bot ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible in Telegram, those bots just provide fake data.

You can't even know who views your channel post via either Client API, Bot API, or unofficial APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I think all of these robots are fake and for ads. actually it's not useful that a robot tell who seen your profile photo. I think it is impossible.

Comment: i agree with these sentence that is fake but isn't useful and fantastic if it was real?!